# is redstone framework dead?

Tags: dart, redstone.dart

The redstone project, http://redstonedart.org/, depends on the DI package, which is dead for quite sometime.
I wonder: is the project redstone also dead?
Or is there any plans to change this scenario?
It is a great package, however, the DI dependency is killing it.
Nowadays I have a version of redstone and DI with me where the dependencies within them are update so I am able to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the main maintainer of the package, I can say that it's in maintenance mode. We still accept PRs, but I'm not putting any effort in any big feature or rewrite at the time.

I don't think it's dead however, but one of the things that is preventing me from doing more updates (for strong mode mainly) is the fact that I'm waiting for the new Angular's DI package to be extracted.

Comment: it's dead. need more characters.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no, I don't think the redstone package will get any major release, but the author started a rewrite of all the framework under a new name but also in pause because of the DI package.

The Angular team planned to extract the DI from Angular but it is plan for 4.0. https://github.com/dart-lang/angular2/issues/16

Comment: Well, that is in fact good News. I will try to use redstone still untill this new package is released

Comment: I don't know if you are the author, but I would like to say that redstone is awesome. I really enjoy it and would like to keep it or use the new project that he is developing. Just, please, keep the metadata style =]